# The ethnicity tags

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

When should one use the ethnicity tags [ashkenazi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashkenazi) and [sephardi-mizrachi-eastern](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sephardi-mizrachi-eastern)?

Should they be used on any question which only applies to one, such as [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14441/yotzros-for-musaf-on-shabbos-shekalim) which talks about a broad custom with a lot of details, but which only applies to Ashkenazim?

Comment: You might wish to split the question into two along the lines of the two answers posted thus far: they seem like two separate questions, no?

Comment: Actually, I've edited out the second question per http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/335/how-to-deal-with-multiple-questions-asked-in-one#comment742_336; please feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, yes, they should be used whenever the question's subject applies to only (e.g.) *Ashk'nazim*. (That's if feasible. Each question can have only five tags.)